# How do I arrange multiple monitors in Xubuntu (22.04) in a VitrualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 11 laptop, with Xubuntu 22.04 installed in a VirtualBox VM.

I would like to get multiple monitors working properly under Xubuntu.

When I fire up the VM and enable all three monitors and go full screen, the three monitors show up, seemingly OK. But windows do not drag properly across the screens.

I fire up `xfce4-display-settings` and the picture shows that monitor 1 is on the left, 2 is in the middle, and 3 is on the right. The physical arrangement is 2 on the left, 1 in the middle, and 3 on the right (when I click "identify" on the "advanced" tab).

I rearrange the icons in the picture and click apply. A dialog box pops up asking me if I want to keep the settings or cancel. Clicking on the keep settings button does nothing. It times out after a few seconds and reverts to the incorrect arrangement of monitors.

So, the question is, how do I rearrange the monitors in `xfce4-display-settings` and make it *stick*?

Comment: I'm astonished that for such a seemingly simple question zero people have any knowledge. Xubuntu and VirtualBox appear to be incompatible where multiple monitors are concerned. I have tried Xubuntu inside a Hyper-V VM, and the screens are arranged properly but there is no way to scale the two side screens. They are 10.1" screens with a resolution of 1920x1200. Microscope required to see anything on them without scaling.

So, shall I just give up on Ubuntu as useless in VMs and look elsewhere for a Linux distro that works?